# Prove for the Fibonacci sequence: $F(m+n) = F(m-1) \cdot F(n) + F(m) \cdot F(n+1)$

Tags: induction, fibonacci-numbers

> The following formula shall be proved by induction:
>   $$F(m+n) = F(m-1) \cdot F(n) + F(m) \cdot F(n+1)$$
>   Where $F(i), i \in \mathbb{N}_0$ is the Fibonacci sequence defined as:
>   $F(0) = 0$, $F(1) = 1$ amd
>   $$F(n+1) = F(n) + F(n-1) \text{ for } n \geq 1.$$

How would you go about this task, especially considering that you have two variables which may be changed? Do you have to look at three cases ($m$ increases, $n$ increases, both $m$ and $n$ increase) in order to fully prove it or is there an easier way?

Comment: You actually only need to prove the case $m\mapsto m+1$ with $n$ kept constant, since the equation is, in fact, symmetric (replacing $n$ by $n-1$)

Comment: This identity have been here couple of times, for example [Showing that an equation holds true with a Fibonacci sequence: $F_{n+m} = F_{n-1}F_m + F_n F_{m+1}$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/11477) and [Product of consecutive Fibonacci numbers divisibility](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1016290)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here is a proof in the same spirit as RobertZ's.

First, let's relate the Fibonacci numbers to the following problem:

> Suppose that you want to go up some flight of stairs and at every step you can take either one or two stairs: in how many ways can you get up the stairs?

Well, if we say that there are $n$ stairs, then it turns out there are $F_{n+1}$ ways to do it.

A very easy inductive proof shows why:

Base cases: If there is $1$ stairs, you can do it in only $1$ way, and indeed $F_{1+1}=F_2=1$.  If there are $2$ stairs, then there are two ways: either take two steps of $1$, or take one step of $2$. And indeed, $F_{2+1}=F_3=2$

Inductive step: Say you have $n >2$ stairs. For your first step you can either go one up or two stairs up. By inductive hypothesis, there are $F_{n}$ ways to finish climbing the $n-1$ stairs after having taken a step of $1$ stairs, and there are $F_{n-1}$ ways to finish climbing the $n-2$ stairs after having taken a step of $2$ stairs. So, there are $F_{n}+F_{n-1}=F_{n+1}$ ways to climb $n$ stairs.

OK, so now that we have made a connection between the Fibonacci numbers and the number of ways to climb stairs in this way, we can prove your desired result very quickly:

Let's climb $m+n-1$ stairs. We now know we can do this in $F_{m+n}$ ways. But note that there are two different possibilities for us climbing those $m+n-1$ stairs:

1. The first way is that as we climb the stairs, we will at some point have climbed *exactly* $n$ stairs. If this happens, then there are $m-1$ stairs left to climb, which can be done in $F_m$ ways. And since then there are $F_{n+1}$ ways to climb the first $n$ stairs, that means that there are $F_m \cdot F_{n+1}$ ways to climb all the $m+n-1$ stairs this way.
2. The second way is that at some point we will have climbed exactly $n-1$ stairs, which can be done in $F_{n}$ ways, after which we take a single step of $2$ stairs, and then finish climbing the remaining $m-2$ stairs. This can therefore be done in  $F_{m-1} \cdot F_{n}$ ways

The total number of ways to climb the $m+n-1$ stairs, then, is the sum of these two ways, and so it must be true that:

$$F_{m+n} = F_{m-1} \cdot F_{n} + F_{m} \cdot F_{n+1}$$

So note that after I established the connection between climbing stairs and the Fobonacci numbers, the proof was straightforward (and did not use induction). But to establish the connection, I used induction.

Comment: Nice variant (+1).  See also https://math.stackexchange.com/a/11527/299698

Comment: @RobertZ :) And here I thought I was original ...

Comment: Have you any suggestion to improve my answer? Unfortunately it did not have much success :-(

Comment: @RobertZ Maybe you could try and show a picture of the domino covering ... both to establish the connection between F numbers and dominoes and then applied to this particular problem

Answer (score 3):

You can get away with inducting on just $n$:

$$ \begin{align} F(m + n) & = F(m + (n - 1)) + F(m + (n -2))\\ 
& = F(m-1)F(n-1) + F(m)F(n) + F(m-1)F(n-2) + F(m)F(n-1) \\
& = F(m-1)[F(n-1) + F(n-2)] + F(m)[F(n)+F(n-1)] \\
& = F(m-1)F(n) + F(m)F(n+1)\end{align}$$

Comment: Can you explain in greater detail the steps you took? You already lost me on the very first one. It seems you have somehow replaced $F(n)$ with the recursive definition of the fibonacci sequence (the last formula I listed), but I didn't even know you can split apart the term partially like that. Isn't the $F(m+n)$ to be seen as static, i.e. if $m=2$ and $n = 3$, you have to solve the entire sum $F(5)$, and can't just partially solve the "3 part" of the fibonacci? Hard to explain my issue, I hope you get what I mean.

Comment: Hi, using your example: if $m = 2, n = 3$, $n + m = 5$ then $F(5) = F(4) + F(3)$ by the definition of the Fibonacci sequence. Note then that $n + m -1 = 4$ and $n + m - 2 = 3$ which is my first step.

Comment: In the second step I induct on $n$, in the third I just gather like terms and in the final I use the fact that $F(n) = F(n-1) + F(n-2)$ and that $F(n+1) = F(n) + F(n-1)$.

Comment: Alright, I've finally understood your solution; thank you! Just for the record, in order to turn it into an actual proof by induction, I believe you have to proof $F(m+n+1) = F(m-1)\cdot F(n+1) + F(m) \cdot F(n+2)$ using the very same steps you took.

Comment: I must revise myself. I think there's an issue here. In the second line, you would apply the induction precondition. If we are inducting on $n$, that means we can only apply it on an $n$, but not e.g. on an $n-1$. But in your calculations you do apply it on just any $n$, so you basically assume that the precondition already applies for every single $n$ (i.e. $n, n+1, n-1, \ldots$) when in reality we only defined it to apply to a fix $n$ for the sake of the proof.

Comment: To prove it's true for $n$, I assume it's true for any $k<n$. Note that I've only applied induction on $n-1$ and $n-2$, which are both strictly less than $n$, so this is all ok.

Answer (score 1):

A combinatorial proof (no induction).

Using the representation of the Fibonacci numbers as the numbers of domino coverings the given identity can be shown in a quick and elegant way.

It is known that the [number of domino coverings of a $2\times N$ grid](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1317885/dominos-2-times-1-on-2-times-n-and-on-3-times-2n) is $F_{N+1}$. Consider the number of domino coverings of a $2\times (m+n-1)$  grid. Any covering can be of two types.

1) The covering has a pair of horizontal dominoes at position $m-1$ and $m$. 
[image]

Therefore on the left side we have a covering of a $2\times (m-2)$ grid
and on the right side we have a covering of a $2\times (n-1)$ grid. Therefore the number of such coverings is
$F_{m-1}\cdot F_{n}$.

2) The covering can be split into two coverings, one of a $2\times (m-1)$ grid and another of a $2\times n$ grid. 
[image]

Therefore the number of such coverings is
$F_{m}\cdot F_{n+1}$.

Finally we may conclude that the number of domino coverings of a $2\times (m+n-1)$  grid is
$$F_{m+n}=F_{m-1}\cdot F_{n}+F_{m}\cdot F_{n+1}.$$

Answer (score 1):

I won't mention every use of induction. Define $$M:=\left(\begin{array}{cc}
0 & 1\\
1 & 1
\end{array}\right),\,V_{n}:=\left(\begin{array}{c}
F_{n}\\
F_{n+1}
\end{array}\right)=M^{n}\left(\begin{array}{c}
0\\
1
\end{array}\right)$$ so $M^{m}=\left(\begin{array}{cc}
F_{m-1} & F_{m}\\
F_{m} & F_{m+1}
\end{array}\right)$ and $$\left(\begin{array}{c}
F_{m+n}\\
F_{m+n+1}
\end{array}\right)=M^{m}\left(\begin{array}{c}
F_{n}\\
F_{n+1}
\end{array}\right)=\left(\begin{array}{c}
F_{m-1}F_{n}+F_{m}F_{n+1}\\
F_{m}F_{n}+F_{m+1}F_{n+1}
\end{array}\right).$$